# Show, hide large image form gallery on click

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am sorry if someone already asked this but i couldn't find an answer. I need to make a simple gallery with 4 pictures (windows style) and when you click on picture a larger picture would appear/pop up and when you click it again it would close.
I was thinking of making a simple table 2x2 with smaller pictures and when you click on any image, a lager one appears on top of everything. I saw a function using "block" and "none" to show / hide picture but i can't make it work.

Tnx!

EDIT:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="frame">

        <table id="galleryTable">

                            <tr>
                              <td><img src="img1.jpg" alt="1" style="width:400px;height:200px;"></td>
                              <td><img src="img2.jpg" alt="2" style="width:400px;height:200px;"></td> 
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td><img src="img3.jpg" alt="1" style="width:400px;height:200px;"></td>
                              <td><img src="img4.jpg" alt="1" style="width:400px;height:200px;"></td> 
                            </tr>

                        </table>
    </div>

    <div>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, i made css design as i want, and now i need js function/functions that will on mouse clich open or enlarge selected image from my table. Or as i understand i can preload pictures in separate div and hide/unhide them. Can someone help me with that functions?

CSS if needed:

```
*{
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px;
}

body{
    font: 12px Arial;
    text-align: center;
}

#frame{
    align-content: center;
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 15px auto;

}

.table, th, td{
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Try something, ask if you have a specific question. (Or if you have tried, post your code!)

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time here.. I edited my post and posted my code.

Comment: You're going to have to learn JavaScript yourself, and then come back and ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
    *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    }

    body{
        font: 12px Arial;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #frame{
        align-content: center;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 15px auto;

    }
    .table, th, td{
        background: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 3px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        color: black;
    }
    .largeImage{
        border:1px solid black;
        display:none;

    }
    </style>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
           jQuery("#galleryTable img").on('click', function(){
                jQuery(".largeImage").empty().append("<img src="+jQuery(this).attr('src')+">").show();
                jQuery("#galleryTable").hide();
            });
            jQuery(".largeImage").on('click', 'img', function(){
                jQuery(".largeImage").empty().hide();
                jQuery("#galleryTable").show();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="frame">
        <table id="galleryTable">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:400px;height:200px;"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/7clxDYpmA-L1XXJP7wcRZMWV71MwDtZhubp1cF8Ss4cVjHFsqisncNP5vavacmMPhds=w300" alt="1"></td>
                <td style="width:400px;height:200px;"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d6Js0wL6riInBUWbxdN5rJjuu_6uygfs-06-8RVRRhDDKC9D4Hs8ZAevLsguTngc0Vkq=w300" alt="2"></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:400px;height:200px;"><img src="http://www.androidfreeware.net/img2/google-now-launcher.png" alt="1"></td>
                <td style="width:400px;height:200px;"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HPc5gptPzRw3wFhJE1ZCnTqlvEvuVFBAsV9etfouOhdRbkp-zNtYTzKUmUVPERSZ_lAL=w300" alt="1"></td> 
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="largeImage"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```